# How to check for multiple files in a directory using If statement in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to look for 2  files in a directory and if both of them are present, I need to echo "Bravo" else "You lost" but I am getting stuck here. If the 1st file is present and 2nd is not, I am getting "You lost" BUT if 1st file is absent and 2nd file is present I am getting "Bravo". Below is my code. Someone please help me.

```
 find /var/tmp/crontab -name crontest|grep crontest
 if [ "$?" eq 0 ]; then
     find /var/tmp/crontab -name cronjob|grep cronjob
     if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then        
         echo "Bravo"
     else
         echo "You lost"
     fi
 fi
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `find`, `grep`, *et al* - you can do it a lot more simply just with bash built-ins, e.g.

```
if [ -e /var/tmp/crontab/crontest ] && [ -e /var/tmp/crontab/cronjob ] ; then 
    echo "Bravo"
else
    echo "You lost"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one liner for this.

```
[ -f /var/tmp/crontab/crontest -a -f /var/tmp/crontab/crontest2 ] &&  \ 
echo "bravo" || echo "lost"
```